# C# class not taking value being pass for LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Hopefully this makes sense. I have a class named `ShippingCont`

In this class, I have a LINQ connection like below. I want to be use this class to call the given table and get all the necessary fields instead of calling individual queries to the DB.

```
    public static ShippingContainerDataContext shippingContainer = new ShippingContainerDataContext();

    public static SHIPPING_CONTAINER sc2 = shippingContainer.SHIPPING_CONTAINERs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CONTAINER_ID == _externalContainerId);


    private string _containerId = sc2.COMPANY;
    private string _company = sc2.COMPANY;

    public string fromProgram
    {
        get { return _externalContainerId; }
    }

    public string ContId
    {
        get { return sc2.CONTAINER_ID; }
        set { _externalContainerId = value; }
    }


    public string _ContainerId
    {
        get { return sc2.CONTAINER_ID; }
        set { _ContainerId = value; }
    }

    public string _Company
    {
        get { return sc2.COMPANY; }
        set { _company = value; }
    }
```

When I try to pass a value to the `_externalContainerId` in the class. The LINQ query returns no records and I get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I know the LINQ returns data because when I manually provide the container ID in the LINQ query like (see below), I get a result set.

`public static SHIPPING_CONTAINER sc2 = shippingContainer.SHIPPING_CONTAINERs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CONTAINER_ID == "00008878742000004419");`

The value is being pass from the main program like below.

`ShippingCont sc = new ShippingCont("00008878742000004419");`

I know the value is being passed because when I call the `fromProgram()` the value prints.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your error occurs because there is no `a.CONTAINER_ID == null`. Have you tried to set `breakpoint` and see the `_externalContainerId`?

Comment: I setup the `breakpoint` and indeed the `_externalContainerId` is `null`. I don't understand why if the value is being set.

Comment: As I see in your code, you have'n declared `_externalContainerID` yet. Maybe thats causin the `null` Try to do this `.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CONTAINER_ID == *some id that exist in your db*);`

Answer (score 0):

Since sc2 is static, the query is probably running before _externalContainerId is set (_externalContainerId = null), which would return empty. It would then remain empty for the duration of the program, because it is not getting recalculated, causing an error when you try to access a member. Since you are setting _externalContainerId in the constructor, you might place the assignment of sc2 in there as well. E.g.

```
public ShippingCont(string id)
{
    this._existingContainerId = id;
    sc2 = shippingContainer.SHIPPING_CONTAINERs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CONTAINER_ID == _externalContainerId);
}    
public static ShippingContainerDataContext shippingContainer = new ShippingContainerDataContext();
public SHIPPING_CONTAINER sc2;
private string _containerId = sc2.COMPANY;
private string _company = sc2.COMPANY;

public string fromProgram
{
    get { return _externalContainerId; }
}

public string ContId
{
    get { return sc2.CONTAINER_ID; }
    set { _externalContainerId = value; }
}


public string _ContainerId
{
    get { return sc2.CONTAINER_ID; }
    set { _ContainerId = value; }
}

public string _Company
{
    get { return sc2.COMPANY; }
    set { _company = value; }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing what you recommended but I got the same result.

Comment: Although, it wasn't the right answer exactly. You pointed me the right direction. I got it to work. Thank you for your help.